# What are ways to improve my PHP data sanitation class?

Tags: php, sql, security, class, sanitization

I'm putting together a site, (we're already using javascript to prevalidate on the client side). However after getting tired of writing mysql_real_escape_string every other line. I wrote this class that only has two functions mainly focused on sanitising data in user-input/sql. My question is, what are ways to achieve easier input-sanitizing and while improving code readability?

```
<?php 
class Safe {
    function userinput($string){
        $string = strip_tags($string);
        $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
        return $string;
    }
    function sql ($string){
       $sqlstuff = Array("union", "select", "update", "delete", "outfile", "create");
       $string = Safe::str($string);
       $string = mysql_escape_string($string);
       $string = str_ireplace($sqlstuff, "", $string);
       return $string;

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It seems like replacing those common words from sql is going to cause problems for you depending on what the client is sending. However I would recommend using a SQL abstraction layer such as PDO and using it's placeholder ability which will do the SQL sanitation. (strip_tags is still a good idea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good idea to use a class like that, particularily if it simplifies input handling. There's however a few points I'd like to comment on:

- You should use mysql_**real_**escape_string instead of the PHP3 mysql_escape_string.
- The first function should be called `html` or something. `userinput` sounds to vague and misrepresentative.
- HTML escaping needs more parameters `htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")` to be perfectly safe
- The blacklisting of dangerous SQL keywords is not a good idea. It hints at a wrong approach to using SQL queries (if you receive queries via HTTP requests, that's your problem).

  - Also you should not attempt to filter them. Instead detected them, write to the error/security log, and die() immediately. If there is an attempt to circumvent security, there's no point in attempting any "cleaning" of the request.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, this is going to sound harsh, but your class is completely broken.

- You should not be using `htmlspecialchars` for sanitizing input, it is only useful for escaping output. You do not need to encode HTML for insertion to the database nor should you. Only using `htmlspecialchars` when sending output to the browser
- You should not be stripping tags from your input, you should be leaving them alone and again using `htmlspecialchars` when you output that data later to insure HTML tags are escaped and not interpreted by the browser
- You should not be using `mysql_escape_string` or `mysql_real_escape_string`, you should be using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). If you are writing a new site there is *absolutely no reason* not to start out correctly and use PDO. *Do it*.
- You should not be filtering out "union", "select", etc, that's dumb. Those words can appear in regular English language, and they're harmless if you're properly escaping quotes which PDO will handle for you.

Again, sorry for the harsh tone of this answer, but scrap the entire thing and use PDO. There is literally nothing salvageable here.

Comment: It's okay, this is my first attempt at this. I will take those points into consideration. The word filtering seemed like a good idea at the time, but I'll check PDO out.

Comment: Hmm I'm looking at the manual for PDO, I can already see there's a lot I don't understand. I'm going to have to have a good read up to do.

Comment: @sto The important thing is to **validate** your input. Make sure numeric things are numeric, that strings aren't too long, that required fields are populated. Let PDO handle escaping things for the database, and let `htmlspecialchars` handle escaping things for the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [filter_*](http://ru.php.net/filter) functions that are bundled with PHP and provide you with the mechanism to filter request parameters according to specific filtering rules.

With [few extra tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995526/php-input-filtering-for-complex-arrays), you could even filter arrays of different types of data (thanks to [erisco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260584/erisco)!).

```
class sanitizer {

  public function sanitizeValues($values, $filters) {

    $defaultOptions=FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE;

    $filters=(array)$filters;
    $values=(array)$values;
    foreach ($filters as $key => $filter) {
        if($parts=explode('/', $key)){
            $v=&$values;
            foreach ($parts as $part){
                $v=&$v[$part];
            }
            $filter=(array)$filter;
            $filter[1]=isset($filter[1])?$filter[1]:$defaultOptions;
            $v=filter_var($v, $filter[0], $filter[1]);
            // consider if you really need this here instead of PDO
            // $v=mysql_real_escape_string($v); 
        }
        else{
            $values[$key]=isset($values[$key]) ? filter_var($values[$key], $filter[0], $filter[1]) : null;
        }

    }
    return $values;
  }
}

$manager=sanitizer::sanitizeValues($_GET['manager'], array(
                 'manager/managerID'=>FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,           
                 'manager/username'=>FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                 'manager/name'=>FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                 'manager/email'=>FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                 'manager/phone'=>FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                 'manager/bio'=>FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                 'manager/enabled'=>FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN,
                 'manager/password'=>FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
```

This will produce an array complete with all the needed fields based on the 'manager' parameter in _GET, with all values filtered and, optionally, escaped.