# PHP: Filtering a multidimensional POST array

Tags: php, post, multidimensional-array, filter

I have the following POST array:

```
[projects] => Array (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [description] => description 1
                [path] => url 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [description] => description2
                [path] => url 2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [description] => description 3
                [path] => url 3
            )

    )
```

And I want it to be filtered with `filter_var_array($_POST, $this -> fields);` where fields = `array('projects' => array('filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK,'flags' => FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY, 'options' => array($this, 'cleanProjects'));`

However, the value passed to the cleanProjects functions is not an array containing a description and a path, but it passes all the values 1 by one (so the method is called six times, 1 for description 1, 1 for url 1, 1 for description2 etc.)

How do I get the filter function to pass the entire object to the callback function?
So it would call cleanProjects for every object/array in projects (3 times in this example).

Comment: If you only want it called once, why bother with `filter_var` at all? Why not just do `$this->cleanProjects($_POST['projects']);`?

Comment: I want it to be called once per project. And the entire post is much bigger, projects is just one field of it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are using now is called [Indirect method call by array variable](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/indirect-method-call-by-array-var) and its only supported by `PHP 5.4 above`

Solution 1 : Upgrade your PHP version and your code would work with out modification

```
        'options' => array($this, 'cleanProjects')));  
                         |_______________________|
                                      +------------ Indirect Method call by array
```

Solution 2 : Just use [Closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

```
    $self = $this ;
    $options = function($args) use ($self)
    {
        $self->cleanProjects($args);
    };

    $this->fields = array('projects' => array(
            'filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK,
            'flags' => FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY, 
            'options' => $options));   // add the closure 
    $var = filter_var_array($_POST, $this -> fields);
```

Comment: 1. I am running 5.4, 2. The problem is not that the method is not being called, it is called to often.

Comment: Yes it would be called on each argument that is the way callback works

Comment: But shouldn't it be called on each item of projects (not each field of each item in project)?

Comment: I think i understand what you want now ... one moment

Comment: You have a valid point ... But that is just the way it works .. here is a walk around http://stackoverflow.com/a/4995863/1226894

Comment: Hmm, not really usable in my case. I ended up json encoding the whole array and decoding it in the callback :(

Comment: that's another good walk around .... with using `$_POST = array_map("json_encode",$_POST);`