# Filtering multi-dimensional POST with PHP filter_input_array

Tags: php, arrays, post, filter, sanitize

Is there a way to filter/sanitize multi-dimensional POST data with PHP's `filter_input_array`?

**Given a form which results in following POST data:**

```
$_POST[
    'level1a' => [
        'level2a' => [
            'key1' => 'value1',
            'key2' => 'value2'
        ],
        'level2b' => [
            'key1' => 'value1',
            'key2' => 'value2'
        ]
    ],
    'level1b' => [
        'level2a' => [
            'key1' => 'value1',
            'key2' => 'value2'
        ],
        'level2b' => [
            'key1' => 'value1',
            'key2' => 'value2'
        ]
    ]
]
```

I don't see a way to tell the `filter_input_array` function that the data to check is nested one level deeper. There seems to be only the flag `FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY`, but no way to tell on which level it needs to check.

**Working example with less dimensions:**

If it was just a less nested set of data, it would be pretty simple:

```
$_POST[
    'level1a' => [
        'level2a' => 'value1',
        'level2b' => 'value2'
    ],
    'level1b' => [
        'level2a' => 'value1',
        'level2b' => 'value2'
    ]
]
```

Could be filtered with:

```
$args = array(
    'level1a' => array(
        'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 
        'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY
    ),
    'level1b' => array(
        'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 
        'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY
    )
);
$form_data = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $args);
```

But how to solve it with more nested data? Is there a way without splitting/flattening the POST data?

Comment: You can probably fairly easily write a recursive function to run `filter_input_array` on some data and then recurse to inner arrays.

Comment: I am working on a similar issue right now. I'll let you know what I come up with.

Comment: I might try engineering my HTML form so that it creates only scalars and/or two-dimensional arrays. Since `$_POST` and `INPUT_POST` are not the same, flattening `$_POST` will not have any effect on `INPUT_POST`. In the pure sense, I think you would want to leave `$_POST` out of it. My suggestion is for you to flatten your HTML form if at all possible, instead of the input source array. Yes, trickery can be done, but at what cost? Processing time? Maintenance? Documentation? Once you get beyond two dimensions, PHP leaves you to your own devices. :) Notice there is no INPUT_FILES.

Comment: You can try the second idea in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4995863

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/**
* Trim and filter every value in the nested array
*/
function filter(array &$array)
{
    array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$value) {
         $value = filter_var(trim($value), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    });

    return $array;
}

/**
* Get filtered POST data
*/
function post(){
  return filter($_POST);
}
```